# Solr Error - Error opening new searcher

Tags: solr, sitecore-install-framework

Please let me know if you need any more information from my side. Attached Screenshots. I am new to Solr and Solr Indexing. Getting error on the master index after opening the Solr URL. I have installed `Sitecore 9.0.2`. I am not seeing this error on Core and Web. Please let me know how to resolve this error.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [mysite_master_index]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$6(CoreContainer.java:593)
    at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:229)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [mysite_master_index]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:964)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$5(CoreContainer.java:564)
    at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:197)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:977)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:830)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:948)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:2069)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:2189)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initSearcher(SolrCore.java:1071)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:949)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: codec header mismatch: actual header=1229866072 vs expected header=1071082519 (resource=MMapIndexInput(path="C:\Solr\solr-6.6.2\server\solr\mysite_master_index\data\index\_ykp_Lucene54_0.dvd"))
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkHeader(CodecUtil.java:196)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkIndexHeader(CodecUtil.java:255)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene54.Lucene54DocValuesProducer.<init>(Lucene54DocValuesProducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene54.Lucene54DocValuesFormat.fieldsProducer(Lucene54DocValuesFormat.java:113)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldDocValuesFormat$FieldsReader.<init>(PerFieldDocValuesFormat.java:294)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldDocValuesFormat.fieldsProducer(PerFieldDocValuesFormat.java:383)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentDocValues.newDocValuesProducer(SegmentDocValues.java:51)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentDocValues.getDocValuesProducer(SegmentDocValues.java:67)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.initDocValuesProducer(SegmentReader.java:164)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.<init>(SegmentReader.java:90)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ReadersAndUpdates.getReader(ReadersAndUpdates.java:145)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ReadersAndUpdates.getReadOnlyClone(ReadersAndUpdates.java:197)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.open(StandardDirectoryReader.java:103)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:467)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:103)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:79)
    at org.apache.solr.core.StandardIndexReaderFactory.newReader(StandardIndexReaderFactory.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:2033)
```

[image]

Comment: What version of Solr do you have installed?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your master_index is corrupted. Easiest fix is to copy the web_index (since it is working fine) and then rename the folder and core.properties file to master_index.

Restart SOLR and also recycle your app pool.

Then go to Sitecore , populate the schema , and then reindex using Sitecore.

Comment: Thanks Abhay, what do you mean by "populate the schema".

Comment: In your sitecore launchpad, go to Control Panel, under Indexing, Select Populate Solr Managed Schema, then select your newly created core.

Comment: Solr uses a defined schema when it works with documents. You can modify an existing schema with,this which automatically populates Sitecore fields and makes sure all fields that Sitecore needs are present.

You can add more fields to this schema by adding fields to the managed-schema file as long as you do not change the system index fields. It is recommend that you only do this after you have populated the Solr schema with the Populate Solr Managed Schema tool. You can use the solr admin schema page to add additional fields. Check https://tinyurl.com/yycqvclu this for more info.